# How to calculate variance of adjacency matrix $A$?

Tags: mathematics, statistics, complex-systems, randomness

I'm studying random matrix theory.

How to calculate variance, $<A_{ij}^2>$ for every $i ≠ j$, if $A$ is a real symmetric $N × N$ uncorrelated random matrix? and I can't understand why the <A_{i,j}> =0 for every i ≠ j?
Could you teach me using random regular graph as an example?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: An explanation for why $\langle A_{i,j}\rangle=0$:

for the expectation value $\langle A_{i,j}\rangle$, since $A_{i,j}$ is a random variable (given this is a random matrix), if $A_{i,j}$ takes on some positive value $|x|$, there is an equal chance that it takes on the negative value $-|x|$, so the expectation value (which is just the average) is precisely zero.